# OpenBSD - How to start x by default?

Tags: x11, login, openbsd

**Question**: How to `startx` by default in OpenBSD?

**Backstory**: I recently reinstalled OpenBSD and it doesn't load the Desktop Environment environment and is text-only upon startup.

Personally, I like pictures. How can I change this? :P

Answer (score 2):

Same as any other unix. If you want a login prompt in graphic mode, install a [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager). [xenodm](https://man.openbsd.org/xenodm.1) is available in the base system. The ports include [gdm](http://openports.se/x11/gnome/gdm) and [kdm](http://openports.se/x11/kde4/workspace).

To activate xenodm, per the [FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq11.html):

```
rcctl enable xenodm
rcctl start xenodm
```

Note that if you log in with a display manager, startx is not involved: `startx` is a command that you can run to start X after logging it in text mode, it can't be used to show a graphical login prompt. When you log in with a display manager, it runs `.xsession` or a program chosen based on your choice of session at login time, not `.xinitrc`.

Comment: Also, since a few months, `Xorg` is no longer installed setuid on OpenBSD, which means that non-privileged user can't use the `startx` command at all.

Comment: @Kusalananda Oh? I thought X didn't need to run as root on OpenBSD. X doesn't run as root on Linux these days. Of course it's because more stuff has been put into the kernel, but I wouldn't have expected OpenBSD to still be running X as root.

Comment: I don't know the details. `xenodm` runs as root, spawns `Xorg`. `Xorg` is started as root (I think) but drops to a `_x11` user after starting an `X` process as root, so there's some degree of privilege separation happening there.

Comment: The (not recommended, but also strangely not even mentioned) workaround for those who want autostart X without the overhead of **xenodm** while accepting the security risks involved, is to set **Xorg** setuid: `chmod +s /usr/X11R6/bin/Xorg`. Then `startx` will work as expected (tested on current OpenBSD, 7.3 amd64 in VirtualBox).